# Gradle throwing error only on Linux

Tags: linux, tomcat, gradle

So whenever I try to do a `gradle startMongoDB`, I get this error:

```
gradle startMongoDB

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/kaspar/Eclipse/workspace/conference-application/app/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method create() for arguments [tomcatRun, class org.gradle.api.plugins.tomcat.tasks.TomcatRun, org.gradle.api.plugins.tomcat.TomcatPlugin$_configureTomcatRun_closure2@1315391f] on task set.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.765 secs
```

This only seems to happen when I try to run it on a Linux machine. On Windows, it works well. What could be the problem?

Please tell me if any more info is needed about the error and I will provide it.

Build.gradle:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper, description: 'Gradle wrapper') {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'

    def jvmOpts = "-Xmx512m"
    inputs.property("jvmOpts", jvmOpts)
    doLast {
        def optsEnvVar = "DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS"
        scriptFile.write scriptFile.text.replace("$optsEnvVar=\"\"", "$optsEnvVar=\"$jvmOpts\"")
        batchScript.write batchScript.text.replace("set $optsEnvVar=", "set $optsEnvVar=$jvmOpts")
    }
}

task downloadMongoDB(description: 'Download and unpack MongoDB database') {

    ext.mongoDBDir = new File('mongoDB')

    if (!mongoDBDir.isDirectory()) {

        ant.mkdir(dir: './mongoDB')
        ant.mkdir(dir: './.tmp')

        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            ant.with{
                get src: 'http://fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-i386-2.4.10-rc0.zip', dest: './.tmp/mongoDB.zip', skipexisting: true
                unzip src: './.tmp/mongoDB.zip', dest: './', overwrite: true
                copydir src: './mongodb-win32-i386-2.4.10-rc0/', dest: './mongoDB/'
                delete dir: './mongodb-win32-i386-2.4.10-rc0', deleteonexit: true
            }
        } else if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_MAC)) {
            ant.with{
                get src: 'http://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.4.10-rc0.tgz', dest: '.tmp/mongoDB.tgz', skipexisting: true
                untar src: '.tmp/mongoDB.tgz', dest: './', overwrite: true, compression: 'gzip'
                copydir src: './mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.4.10-rc0/', dest: './mongoDB/'
                delete dir: './mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.4.10-rc0', deleteonexit: true
            }
        } else if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_UNIX)) {
            // Needs testing
            ant.with{
                get src: 'http://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-i686-2.4.10-rc0.tgz', dest: '.tmp/mongoDB.tgz', skipexisting: true
                untar src: '.tmp/mongoDB.tgz', dest: './', overwrite: true, compression: 'gzip'
                copydir src: './mongodb-linux-i686-2.4.10-rc0/', dest: './mongoDB/'
                delete dir: './mongodb-linux-i686-2.4.10-rc0', deleteonexit: true
            }
        } else {
            throw new StopExecutionException("Unknown operating system")
        }
    }
}

task repairMongoDB(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'downloadMongoDB', description: 'Repair MongoDB database') {
    workingDir projectDir.path

    ant.mkdir(dir: './data/db')

    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        commandLine '.\\mongoDB\\bin\\mongod', '--dbpath', '.\\data\\db', '--logpath', '.\\data\\db\\mongodb.log', '--rest', '--logappend', '--repair'
    }else{
        // After unpack the files do not have executable permission
        FileTree tree = fileTree('./mongoDB/bin').include('*');
        tree.each { File file ->
            file.setExecutable(true);
        }
        commandLine './mongoDB/bin/mongod', '--dbpath', './data/db', '--logpath', './data/db/mongodb.log', '--rest', '--logappend', '--repair'
    }
}

task startMongoDB(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'repairMongoDB', description: 'Run MongoDB database') {

    workingDir projectDir.path

    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        commandLine '.\\mongoDB\\bin\\mongod','--port', '27017', '--dbpath', '.\\data\\db', '--logpath', '.\\data\\db\\mongodb.log', '--logappend', '--rest'
    }else{
        commandLine './mongoDB/bin/mongod', '--port', '27017', '--dbpath', './data/db', '--logpath', './data/db/mongodb.log', '--logappend', '--rest'
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply from: project.rootDir.path + "/gradle-include/eclipse.gradle"

    if(project.file('src/main').exists()) {
        apply from: project.rootDir.path + "/gradle-include/maven.gradle"
    }
}
```

Comment: Pasting `build.gradle` might be helpful.

Comment: Edited my post with it

Comment: Fixed the problem by installing the latest gradle: (1.11).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by installing the latest cradle (1.11)